# Is it better to have one instance of new form when using ShowDialog or create new every time form is shown ? - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple winform application in c#. It displays data on the data grid view control, when user double click on the row, another (Not MDI) form is displayed showing related date on the new form.

New form has one data table type variable and one read only data grid view, i am assigning new data source to grid every time user clicks on the grid row (on parent window).

Is it better to create a new instance of a form at class level and display form using show dialog Or should i use the using statement every time user double clicks on the row?

**Method 1**

```
MyForm _form = new MyForm();

void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _form.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

**Method 2**

```
void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      using (MyForm _form = new MyForm())
      {
        _form.ShowDialog(this);
       }

}
```

Comment: It depends if you want to uses the previous properties.  Every time you create the form with the constructor "NEW" you loose all the previous properties on the Form.  So if you want to keep old values you cannot dispose the old form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Thanks. I am using show dialog which i think doesn't work in a same way. I could be wrong.

Comment: The difference between Show() and ShowDialog() is the Show() method you can return from the form without disposing while ShowDialog() you have to close/dispose form so you can return.  You can just change from ShowDialog() to Show().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 2, with the "using" keyword, is much cleaner and safer.

Keeping the form in memory could lead to strange behaviors that are difficult to debug. For example, if the form has a timer that shows a messagebox every 5 seconds (as a simple test) that messagebox will continue to pop up even after you "close" the form if you do not dispose it after use, which is what "using" would clean up for you. Even if you intend to keep the previous properties, it would be better to keep just the properties and not the form itself, and pass the properties to the form each time you instantiate it. There are other, less obvious things (like values changing in referenced objects) that you could waste hours tracking down.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really want.

Example:
You need to create a chat form for you application.
Runned form loads a large history from a database.
In this case the best decision is not to renew your form.

Comment: Fair point. I would argue that passing the filled dataset (generic list, whatever) into a new copy would be a better option, eliminating data synchronization issues between forms among other things.

Answer (score 0):

In C#,  variables both should be scoped as tightly as possible. The second example allows you to use a local variable instead of a field, so it is “better," although you shouldn't use an underscore for a local variable name.

```
void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MyForm form = new MyForm())
    {
        form.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

However, if you find that you have a performance issue loading and unloading the form repeatedly, or if you need to persist state in the form, it is perfectly OK to use the first example. Just remember to dispose the field.

```
MyForm _form = new MyForm();

void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form.ShowDialog(this);
}

public override void Dispose()
{
    _form.Dispose();
    base.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: In your second example, there will always be a single instance of a MyForm so at what point would you call the dispose method?

Comment: If it is the main form for your application, it will get disposed by the runtime when your application ends. strictly speaking it’s not completely necessary, as ending the process will also dispose all the resources. But it’s good practice, especially if you may introduce more forms at a later time.